# "Cannot read property 'map' of undefined" when utilizing .map to create various JSX components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am having a bit of an issue when attempting to .map a React state variable into various JSX elements. I have noticed that the state variable I am storing the array within is not undefined, as "console.log-ing" the variable appears to hold the information I need it to. The error according to my React Development Page mentions the error [starts at line 43](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mn803.png) Here is my code for the main Dashboard.js I am utilizing the .map function within to create new list items.

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import {generateId} from '../../Utilities/generateId.js';
import {expirationTime} from '../../Utilities/expirationTime.js';
import {Form} from '../Form/Form.js';
import {Thought} from '../Thought/Thought.js';

export function Dashboard() {
    // Sets up sample message when site first loads up; eventually disappears after 15s
    // generateId adheres an id number starting at 0, to each thought to easily identify each thought
    // expirationTime sets the automatic removal of the "thought" 15 seconds away from current time
    const [thoughts, setThoughts] = useState([
        {
        id: generateId(),
        text: "Add your thoughts, don't be shy!",
        expires: expirationTime(),
        }, 
        {
        id: generateId(),
        text: 'They disappear after 15 seconds!',
        expires: expirationTime(), 
        }
    ]);

    //adds new thought object to array lists out all collective thoughts in thoughts array
    const addThought = (thought) => {
        setThoughts((prev) => [thought, ...prev]);
    };

    const removeThought = (thoughtID) => {
        //reuses state and uses filter function to cycle through each object in the thoughts array,
        // and remove the thought whose ID matches the one that was selected(clicked) on
        setThoughts((prev) => {
            prev.filter((thought) => thought.id !== thoughtID)
        });
    };

    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Thought Machine</h1>
            <h3>Welcome! This is an open space for any of your thoughts.</h3>
            <h2>Thanks for visiting!</h2>
            <Form addThought={addThought} />
            <ul className='thoughts'>
                {thoughts.map( thought => 
                    (<Thought key={thought.id} thought={thought} removeThought={removeThought} />) 
                    // thought.text
                )}
            </ul>
        </div>
    )
};
```

Aside from the main code here, here is my code for Thought.js, where I pass in my props for the "thoughts" I am attempting to individually list out. I do not believe there is any issue with my code here, yet I am posting it just in case.

Thought.js:

```
import React, {useEffect} from 'react';

export function Thought(props) {
    const {thought, removeThought} = props;

    useEffect(() => {
        const timeRemaining = thought.expirationTime - Date.now();

        const timeout = setTimeout(() => {
            removeThought(thought.id)
        }, timeRemaining);

        return () => {
            clearTimeout(timeout);
        }
    }, [thought]);

    const handleRemoveClick = () => {
        removeThought(thought.id);
    };

    return (
        <li className='Thought'>
            <button className='remove-button' onClick={handleRemoveClick}>&times;</button>
            <p className='text' >{thought.text}</p>
        </li>
    )
};
```

I also do not believe that there is any issue with my code for the Form, yet here is that following code just in case my judgment is incorrect.

Form.js:

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import {generateId} from '../../Utilities/generateId.js';
import {expirationTime} from '../../Utilities/expirationTime.js';

import './Form.css';

export function Form(props) {
    const [text, setText] = useState('');

    //this function is called everytime the text value in the entry box is changed... adjusts state value of text
    const handleTextChange = (event) => {
        setText(event.target.value);
    };

    const handleSubmit = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();

        //sets object for new thought and fills in new message; new generated ID and new time 15 seconds ahead of current time
        const thought = {
            id: generateId(),
            text: text,
            expiresAt: expirationTime(),
        };
        
        // checks if text has any text within it, then submits the new 'thought' to props.addThought
        if (text.length > 0) {
            props.addThought(thought);
            // sets text state back to blank after submitting new thought
            setText('');
        }
    }

    return (
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} className='Form'>
            <input value={text} onChange={handleTextChange} type='text' placeholder="Go ahead ... there's no CIA agents here :)" />
            <input type='submit' value='add' />
        </form>
    );
};
```

Apologies for the convoluted-ness of the question and thanks ahead of time for any assistance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**May be** you are getting an error `undefined` at line `43` at the time of **updating** because of this code

```
const removeThought = (thoughtID) => {
        setThoughts((prev) => {
            return prev.filter((thought) => thought.id !== thoughtID) <---- You have to return as well
        });
    };
```

---

**Explanation**

When you are setting state while `updating`, you are returning `nothing`, thus the state is settled to `undefined` and we `can't` `map` over undefined.